# Is it possible to run reduce on a stream in elixir?

Tags: elixir

Is it possible to reduce a Stream in elixir?

I see Stream.scan but it does not return the accumulator.

```
file_stream
|> Stream.each(&parse_line/1)
|> Enum.reduce(&reduce_fn/2)
```

I seem to be running into issues with the follow but was wondering if it is okay to do?

Comment: `Enum.reduce` should works fine on non-infinite streams (like a file stream). What is your `reduce_fn/2` function doing, and what kind of issues are you facing?
Also, please note that [`Stream.each/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Stream.html#each/2) will not transform the stream, you might be looking for [`Stream.map/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Stream.html#map/2)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no sense in reducing a stream. The core difference between functions in `Enum` module vs `Stream` would be, the former is greedy while the latter is lazy.

That said, `Stream` produces a set of transformations that could be lazily applied on per collection’s element basis, passing through.

But `reduce` (aka `foldl`) is already an effectively greedy operation, one cannot get to the result without going through the whole collection. (That is why `Stream.scan/3` does not return the accumulated value back, by the way.)

---

**Enum**

```rb
#  ===== code =====        ===== piped through =====
[1, 2, 3]                        # [1, 2, 3]
#                                #     ⇓
|> Enum.map(&IO.inspect/1)       # [1, 2, 3]
#                                #     ⇓
|> Enum.map(&IO.inspect/1)       # [1, 2, 3]

#⇒ 1 2 3 1 2 3
```

**Stream**

```rb
#  ===== code =====        ===== piped through =====
[1, 2, 3]                        # 1  2  3
#                                # ⇓  ⇓  ⇓
|> Stream.map(&IO.inspect/1)     # 1  2  3
#                                # ⇓  ⇓  ⇓
|> Stream.map(&IO.inspect/1)     # 1  2  3
|> Enum.to_list()                # termination!
#                                # ⇒  ⇒  ⇒

#⇒ 1 1 2 2 3 3
```

Comment: Then how come it says it is Eager like all Enum fns here https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/enumerables-and-streams.html#eager-vs-lazy

Comment: Well, eager = greedy. `Enum.reduce/3` is eager, inexisting `Stream.reduce/3` would have been lazy by a convention, but `reduce` is always eager, hence it’s there in `Enum` only.

Comment: How could we do something like a reduce on a stream? Iterating through all and keeping track of an accumulator?

Comment: I am not sure I follow. Keeping track of the accumulator _already_ means one cannot embed `reduce` into `Stream` chain. Lazy processing means the first element of the input goes _through all the transformations_, then the second one etc. This is impossible if in the middle one goes through all the elements. This step would be terminating the `Stream`. I’ll add the “picture” to the answer.

Comment: Added. When one has a huge list, the eager operation would produce an intermediate result on each step (another huge list in the case of e. g. `map`) and it might be very memory consuming. `Stream` lazily passes it element by element to the _transformations_ producing no intermediate result at all.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to accumulate some value, you're likely looking for `Stream.transform/3`, `Stream.transform/4`, or `Stream.transform/5`.  This would allow you to retain an accumulator, which is usually why one would reach for reduce on an enumerator.

For example, the docs show how Stream.take(enum, n) is implemented with the following:

```
enum = 1001..9999
n = 3
stream = Stream.transform(enum, 0, fn i, acc ->
  if acc < n, do: {[i], acc + 1}, else: {:halt, acc}
end)

Enum.to_list(stream)
[1001, 1002, 1003]
```

More here: https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.12.3/Stream.html#transform/3